# Change of Variables from Sphere to Plane

Tags: geometry, analysis, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations

Say we are in the space $\mathbb{R}^{n}$. Consider the $n-1$ dimensional surface measure $dS$ on the boundary of the upper half sphere. We can define the coordinates on this sphere by $(x_{1},x_{2},...,x_{n-1}, \gamma(x_{1},...,x_{n}))$. Now, say we do a change of variables where we project $(x_{1},x_{2},...,x_{n-1}, \gamma(x_{1},...,x_{n}))$ to $(x_{1},x_{2},...,x_{n-1}, 0)$ which has Lebesgue measure, $dx = dx_{1}\cdot...\cdot dx_{n}$ in $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$.

How can I show the change of variable $dS = (1+|D\gamma|^{2})^{\frac{1}{2}} dx$.

$D$ is the gradient in n-1 dimensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a general surface( not necessarily to be a sphere) S parameterized by a graph of a function $\gamma$, $S=\{(x^1, ..., x^{n-1}, \gamma(x^1,...,x^{n-1}))\}$, its tangent vectors are $$\frac{\partial}{\partial{x^i}}=(0,...,1,0,...,0,\gamma_i)$$, where $\gamma_i=\frac{\partial\gamma}{\partial{x^i}}$. Elements of its first fundamental form is
$$g_{ij}=\langle \frac{\partial}{\partial{x^i}}, \frac{\partial}{\partial{x^j}}\rangle=\gamma_i\gamma_j(i\ne j)$$, and
$$g_{ii}=\langle \frac{\partial}{\partial{x^i}}, \frac{\partial}{\partial{x^i}}\rangle=1+\gamma_i^2$$.
So we have $g=(g_{ij})=I+(\gamma_i\gamma_j)$. Since $\det(\lambda I-g)=\det((\lambda-1)I-(\gamma_i\gamma_j))$, and since $(\gamma_i\gamma_j)$ and $(\gamma_i\gamma_j)^t$ have the same non-zero eigenvalues, which has only one non-zero eigenvalue $\sum\gamma_i^2=|D\gamma|^2$, we conclude that eigenvalues of $g$ is $(1+|D\gamma|^2, 1, ..., 1)$, thus $\det g=1+|D\gamma|^2$. Q.E.D.